# JSON Error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

Tags: java, android, json, gson

```
public interface UserService {
    @POST(Constants.Api.URL_REGISTRATION)
    @FormUrlEncoded
    BaseWrapper registerUser(@Field("first_name") String firstname, @Field("last_name") String lastname, @Field("regNumber") String phone, @Field("regRole") int role);


 public BaseWrapper registerUser(User user) {
        return getUserService().registerUser(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getPhone(), user.getRole());
    }
```

This create Exception

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Big thanks for help.

Comment: your json is wrong, correct it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Let's look at the error you are receiving.

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT

Your JSON is an object, and all JSON objects are enclosed in curly braces ({}). BEGIN_OBJECT is therefore {. And it's expecting it somewhere.

> but was STRING

But instead he found a string "Something". Still doesn't tell us where.

> at line 1 column 1 path $

Ah, perfect. At line 1 column 1. Which is the start of the JSON. So you have forgotten to enclose the whole thing in {} (or at least you have forgotten the first one, but I bet you've forgotten them both).

Comment: Note that JSON could also be enclosed in square brackets ( [ ] ), if it is an array

Comment: Excellent explanation with nice formatting.  +1 to you.

Comment: @OO7 @SnyersK @Astrogat How can I avoid crash my app - I get this error when trying to format API errorBody response (when I wrong request for e.g. 25 times in 10 sec)... I've got `catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e)` but it doesn't help...

Comment: Dear @Astrogat I have an interceptor in my server not called at all, however I get this error!!! please help

Answer (score 2):

Recently i'd faced similiar issue and solutioned only by adding **"Accept: application/json"** into header section. So, if you're using retrofit 2.0;

**1st solution:** For post method add headers parameter like below;

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
@POST(Constants.Api.URL_REGISTRATION)
@FormUrlEncoded
BaseWrapper registerUser(@Field("first_name") String firstname, 
                         @Field("last_name") String lastname, 
                         @Field("regNumber") String phone, 
                         @Field("regRole") int role);
```

**2nd solution:** Add header into your interceptor class like this;

NB: Code is in kotlin

```
private fun getInterceptor(): Interceptor {
        try {
            return Interceptor {
                val request = it.request()
                it.proceed(
                    request.newBuilder()
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .header("Authorization", "$accessTokenType $accessToken")
                        .build()
                )
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            throw Exception(exception.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning and rebuilding the project works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the ArrayList in the json object and parse in GSON then make sure the ArrayList should be like below.

```
ArrayList<JSONObject>
```

Instead of

```
ArrayList<String>
```

and Parse like this.

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> mItem = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
mItem.add(jsonObject);

// and Use like this.
JSONArray list = new JSONArray(mItem);
jsonObject.put("Item",list);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app was using stored data from previous version and you changed the data type, you may encounter this error.

For example: I had something stored as a String in my previous version. I later updated the class that had the data stored in it to an object type. When I ran it, I got this error. After clearing the app-data or re-installing it, the error cleared.

Clearing the app-data might be an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

In Kotlin we can use Response of ResponseBody and manage the initial response within it.

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        mainRepository.getAPIData(
            Constants.getRequestBody(requestBody.toString())
        ).let { it ->
            if (it.isSuccessful && it.code() == 200) {
                val responseBody = it.body()
                val res: String? = responseBody?.string()
                try {
                    val main = JSONObject(res!!)
                    Log.e("TAG", "onSuccess: " + main.toString())
                    if (main.getInt("StatusCode") == 200) {
                        val type = object : TypeToken<Response>() {}.type
                        val response: Response = Gson().fromJson(
                            main.toString(), type
                        )
                        Log.e("TAG", "onSuccess: " + response.toString())
                    } else {
                        apiResponseData.postValue(Resource.error(main.getString("Message"), null))
                        Log.e("TAG", "onFail: " + main.toString())
                    }
                } catch (exception: JSONException) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Exception: " + exception.message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Response - Retrofit**

**ResponseBody - okHttp**

**Response** is actual model Response e.g. UserResponse

Here, getAPIData() is API call which returns Response of ResponseBody

**apiResponseData** is MutableLiveData

using this you can avoid JSON type cast error in response.

Answer (score 0):

It's a proguard problem. In release minifyEnabled true broke the API models.
You need to add Serializable in ResponseModel and in RequestModel API

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHN22.png