# Retrofit Error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I want to retrive data from server...This is my method to call

```
private void getBooks(){
    //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog

    //Creating a rest adapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();

    //Creating an object of our api interface
    IApiMethods api = adapter.create(IApiMethods.class);

    api.getBooks("78", new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void success(JSONObject jsonObject, Response response) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),jsonObject.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("response",jsonObject.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            Log.e("error",error.getMessage());

        }
    });



}
```

This is my interface

```
     public interface IApiMethods {

      @FormUrlEncoded
      @POST("/product_info.php")
      public void getBooks(@Field("cid") String cid, Callback<JSONObject> jsonObjectCallback);

   }
```

I am getting error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $.

Please help me..For the first time i am using retofit library.

Comment: wrong json formate retuned by server. I think not started with {.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424372/json-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-object-but-was-strin

Answer (score 2):

Your server is returning something like 
`"your string from the server"` instead of returning a JSON object:

```
{prop1: val1, prop2: val2, ...}
```

Either you need to change the response of you server to send back a JSON object or you need to change your interface definition to expect to **String**:

```
public interface IApiMethods {

  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("/product_info.php")
  public void getBooks(@Field("cid") String cid, Callback<String> jsonObjectCallback);

}
```