# Not able to compare two json files with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to compare two JSON strings. Below is my code in Java:

```
String json1 = "C:\\test1.json";
String json2 = "C:\\test2.json";

Gson g = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(json1, mapType);
Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(json2, mapType);
System.out.println(Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap));
```

and below is my JSON file format

**My Json 1**

```
{
    "00601":{
        "type":"zipcode",
        "assignment":"South Monroe, MI"
        },
    "00602":{
        "type":"zipcode",
        "assignment":"South Monroe, MI"
        },
    "00603":{
        "type":"zipcode",
        "assignment":"South Monroe, MI"
        }
}
```

**My Json 2**

```
{
    "00601":{
        "type":"zipcode",
        "assignment":"South Monroe, MI"
        },
    "00602":{
        "type":"zipcode",
        "assignment":"South Monroe, MI"
        },
    "00603":{
        "type":"zipcode",
        "assignment":"South Monroe, MI"
        }
}
```

I have gone through [JSON Error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424372/json-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-object-but-was-strin)

but still facing the issue:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

Comment: So the issue is `Gson#fromJson` throwing some exception? Maybe you could rephrase the question and post the full stacktrace..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `json1`, which is `C:\test1.json` internally, is not valid JSON, and similarly for `json2`. They **looks like names of files which *contain* JSON**. If so, you need to either:

- read the *contents* of the (each) file into a `String`, possibly going through other types like a `StringBuilder` or `CharBuffer` on the way, and pass that `String` to `.fromJson`
- create a `Reader` that reads the contents of the file, and pass that to the `.fromJson(Reader,Type)` method instead of the `(String,Type)` one; if the data in the file is in or compatible with your JVM's default encoding (and ASCII-only data such as your example is compatible with all encodings used as JVM defaults) then `FileReader` is suitable for this and can be constructed from a filename with [`new FileReader(String)` as documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader-java.lang.String-)

In a serious or larger program you should be careful to `close` a `FileReader`, or other method of reading the file like a `FileInputStream`, after using it to avoid tying up resources. Assuming Java8, `try-with-resources` is usually the most convenient way to do this.

Comment: yes you r right i did a silly mistake thanks for figuring it out.