# Retrofit's onFailure method gets called even after right response

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

Following is my request parameters in PostMan

```
{"assign_id":"1","type":2,"attendance_list":[{"stud_id":"1703","attendanceID":"1","stud_attendance":"4"},{"stud_id":"1704","attendanceID":"2","stud_attendance":"1"},{"stud_id":"1705","attendanceID":"3","stud_attendance":"1"},{"stud_id":"1706","attendanceID":"4","stud_attendance":"1"},{"stud_id":"1707","attendanceID":"5","stud_attendance":"1"},{"stud_id":"1727","attendanceID":"25","stud_attendance":"1"}]}
```

Following is the response

```
{"status":1,"msg":"Success"}
```

Now in my Android App I am using Retrofit with Gson. But passing through Gson, I was facing some problem so I am sending request parameters in form of `jsonObject` and `jsonArrays`.

Following is my code when a button is pressed to submit request to server

```
val jObjRequest = JsonObject()

                jObjRequest.addProperty("assign_id",ClassModelInstance.getInstance().classInfo.assignId)
                jObjRequest.addProperty("type","2")
                val attendanceArray = JsonArray()
                for(i in 0 until ClassModelInstance.getInstance().studentInfos.size){
                    val jsonObject = JsonObject()
                    jsonObject.addProperty("stud_id",ClassModelInstance.getInstance().studentInfos[i].studId)
                    jsonObject.addProperty("attendanceID",1)
                    jsonObject.addProperty("stud_attendance",ClassModelInstance.getInstance().studentInfos[i].studAttendance)
                    attendanceArray.add(jsonObject)
                }

                jObjRequest.addProperty("attendance_list",attendanceArray.toString())
                Log.i("PritishAttendanceApi2", jObjRequest.toString())

                val submitAttendanceInterface = ApiClient.client.create(SubmitAttendanceInterface::class.java)

                submitAttendanceInterface.takeAttendance(jObjRequest)
                                .enqueue(object : Callback<SubmitAttendanceResponse> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<SubmitAttendanceResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        activity?.let { it1 -> ToastMaker.make(it1,getString(R.string.something_went_wrong),Toast.LENGTH_LONG) }
                        Log.i("Pritish",t.message+"\t"+t.localizedMessage+"\t"+t.printStackTrace()+"\t"+t.cause+"\n"+call.request())
                        alertDialog.dismiss()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<SubmitAttendanceResponse>, response: Response<SubmitAttendanceResponse>) {
                        if(response.body()?.status.toString().equals("1",true)){
                            activity?.let { it1 -> ToastMaker.make(it1,response.body()?.msg.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG) }
                            goToPreviousFragment()
                        } else {
                            activity?.let { it1 -> ToastMaker.make(it1,response.body()?.msg.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG) }
                        }

                        alertDialog.dismiss()
                    }

                })
```

This is the interface and response class

```
interface SubmitAttendanceInterface {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("timetable/takeAttendance")
    fun takeAttendance(@Body body: JsonObject): Call<SubmitAttendanceResponse>

}

data class SubmitAttendanceResponse(
        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        var status: Int? = null,
        @SerializedName("msg")
        @Expose
        var msg: String? = null

)
```

When I log using `HttpInterceptor` I get `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path`

I searched Stack Overflow for the above error but the answers didn't met my requirement

[JSON Error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424372/json-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-object-but-was-strin)

["Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

I have edited the url in the logs as I don't want to expose the URL.

Comment: add httplogginginterceptor to your retrofit client to get the log of network call

Comment: @Nudge Please check are you using correct url for the post request and posting correct json body to server.

Comment: @ManthanPatel i am using that. Please read the question again i have mentioned it. If you want i can send you the logs

Comment: Yes send the log

Comment: @Nainal I am using the correct url. I checked it.

Comment: @ManthanPatel Please check the question . I have added the logs. I have edited the url in the logs as i dont want to expose the url

Comment: you are getting some more data 
                <p style="margin-left:10px">
                File: /home/diceapp/public_html/dize/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php<br />
                Line: 815<br />
                Function: set_status_header         </p>

Comment: @ManthanPatel I dont think so i should be  getting more data as Postman,Volley and ios gives the data i mentioned above in the question

Comment: try jObjRequest.addProperty("attendance_list",attendanceArray) insted of jObjRequest.addProperty("attendance_list",attendanceArray.toString())  in your sample data you are passing as an array and your logcat says it is string

Comment: @ManthanPatel if i remove toString() i am getting error at addProperty

Comment: sorry there was typo try this jObjRequest.add("attendance_list",attendanceArray)

Comment: @ManthanPatel its working. Please post it as an answer

Comment: Nudge, your posts are still too sloppy, as per my previous remarks. Please trim back the chatty material, and use an upper case letter when referring to yourself ("I"). These are not particularly onerous requests. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site where technical writing is appropriate, and it is not a chat-room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your log and sample data you should post data "attendance_list" as an json array insted of string

try
`jObjRequest.add("attendance_list",attendanceArray)` 
insted of 
`jObjRequest.addProperty("attendance_list",attendanceArray.toString())`