# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, json, gson

Data Post on Database. Its give Result Json Format.

```
{"response":"exist"}
```

When get Response using Retrofit Library and json Parsing using GSON .its goes on OnFailure method and its give error.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Register>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<Register> call, Response<Register> response) {


               if (response.body().equals("ok")){

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration is Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }else if (response.body().equals("exiest")){

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Already Exiest", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }else if(response.body().equals("error")){

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<Register> call, Throwable t) {

               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
       });
```

Error is :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

how it Resolved its Please Guide Me.

Comment: have you added addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) to your retrofit builder

Comment: post your Register model here

Comment: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
                    

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

Comment: @POST("Registration.php")
    Call<Register> registerUser(@Field("fname") String fName,
                                @Field("mname") String mName,
                                @Field("lname") String lName,
                                @Field("mobile_no") String mobile,
                                @Field("email_id") String email);

Comment: @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    public String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing your response wrong . and its `exist` , you are comparing `exiest`

change your parsing  like this

```
if (response.body().getResponse().equals("ok")){

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration is Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }else if (response.body()..getResponse().equals("exist")){

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Already Exiest", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("error")){

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing your Data wrong. Retrofit convert response in Register model class as given in Callback, you should read the value from this.

```
Register register= response.body();
if (register.getResponse().equals("ok")){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration is Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else if (register.getResponse().equals("exist")){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else if(register.getResponse().equals("error")){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

**Register.java**

```
public class Register {
    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    private String response;
    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you receive proper JSON output in your response?

Comment: {"response":"exist"}

Comment: i have received above JSON output.

Comment: This error can't occur if you receive the above output. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425418/1546759